# raphael: show HTML entity within a tag

Tags: svg, raphael, html-entities, graphael

I want to add HTML entity to raphael tag, but I see the text deg and not the degree sign -

```
this.tags.push(
  // make tag (x, y, text, degree, radius)
  r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i]+ "&deg;C", 20, 4).insertBefore(this) ...
```

How can I escape it?

I am not sure which language actually displays this text, HTML, JavaScript or SVG ...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also pass fromCharCode to a raphael node.

```
r.text(100, 100, String.fromCharCode(176));
```

would render the ° entity in a text node.

Answer (score 3):

In general you'll be working with a UTF encoded file, and in that case you can just enter the
degree character, `°`, as such.